# how to migrate oracle data to greenplum database

Tags: oracle, greenplum

how to migrate Oracle data to the Greenplum database
is there any way that we can migrate the data from Oracle to the Greenplum database, like a tool 
is there any tool available to migrate Oracle data to the Greenplum database like SSMA

Answer (score 0):

[Outsourcer](http://www.pivotalguru.com/?page_id=20)

[Attunity Replicate](https://www.attunity.com/products/replicate/)

[Talend](https://www.talend.com/resources/integrating-greenplum/)

[Informatica](https://greenplum-informatica.docs.pivotal.io/1-0/overview.html)

You can also use something as simple as sqlplus to dump the data and then Greenplum external tables to load the files into Greenplum tables.

Answer (score 0):

Informatica Powercenter is a paid tool , which can do the task
Talend Data Studio is kinda free , should be ready to do experiment and fix the connector issues on your own.